# How to interpret the coefficient on a covariate in a competing risks survival analysis model?

Tags: survival, regression-coefficients, competing-risks

Consider the results of a competing risks survival analysis model published in a journal. The model examines the relationship between legislatures and coups. Legislature, the main explanatory variable, is a binary indicator that takes a value of 0 if no legislature is present if 1 if a legislature present. The authors write: "A positive coefficient implies that a covariate lowers a dictator’s risk of leaving office by the associated type of exit."

I am slightly confused by this, as my thought was that a positive coefficient in survival analysis would imply that a covariate is associated with increased hazard and decreased survival times. However, the authors interpret the coefficient on Legislature as follows: "The existence of . . . a legislature . . . has a large, positive, and statistically significant negative effect on the risk of coups." Would a negative coefficient imply that having a legislature is associated with an increased likelihood of experiencing a coup?

Comment: Is this question different from the newer https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/624978?